# Is this use of atomic correct?

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking, atomic

i have the following hierarchy:

```
struct Point
{
  std::atomic<int> x;
  std::atomic<int> y;
  std::atomic<int> z;
}

class Data
{
 std::atomic<int> version;
 Point point;
}

unordered_map<std::string,Data> hashtable; // global
```

Thread1 is the producer:

Thread 1 receive a `std::pair<std::string,Point> new_data`, it does:

```
shared_hashtable[new_data.first].point.x.store(new_data.second.x,memory_order_release) // update X 
shared_hashtable[new_data.first].point.y.store(new_data.second.y,memory_order_release) // update Y
shared_hashtable[new_data.first].point.z.store(new_data.second.z,memory_order_release) // update Z
hashtable[new_data.first].version.store(hashtable[new_data.first].version+1,memory_order_release) // update the version of the data
```

Thread 2 does:

```
int local_version;
while(local_version!=shared_hashtable["string1"].version.load(memory_order_acquire))
{
  //...process data...
 local_version=shared_hashtable["string1"].version.load(memory_order_acquire);
 }
```

Does the memory order passed guarantee that my store and load wont be reordered. 
Does the design work as expected : if the object at `hastable["string1"]` is updated, will I process the corresponding data in thread 2 ?

Comment: I do not see a design whatsoever, you play concurrency on elementary scope, which is no good.

Comment: Well I want the global object to be updated and the different thread to be able to catch these updates. I'm trying to do this without constructing a new object each time, just updating the existing one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hashtable` isn't protected against simultaneous access, and its `operator[]` is not `const`. If you guarantee that (1) `hashtable["string1"]` is inserted into the table before these two threads try to access it, and (2) no other threads are writing to `hashtable` during the time these two threads are running, the lookups in `hashtable` won't result in a data race. If you can't guarantee (1) and (2), then you need to protect the lookups with a mutex. `unordered_map` invalidates iterators when it rehashes, but references stay valid until the referenced item is removed from the map.

The memory model guarantees you that the writes in thread 1 that precede the `memory_order_release` write to `version` are visible to thread 2 after it `memory_order_acquire` reads the corresponding value from `version`. This would be the case even if the accesses to the `Point` members were non-atomic.

However, it is possible that the reads of the `Point` members in thread 2 see values from a *later* write in thread 1, so you are not guaranteed that the three `Point` members read in thread 2 correspond to a particular `Point` that was actually written by thread 1. I imagine you need a guarantee that the `Point` processed by thread 2 is in fact some `Point` written by thread 1 and not an aggregate of the values of multiple different points (e.g., `x` from version 1, `y` from version 2, `z` from version 3). Changing the design from

```
struct Point { atomic<int> x, y, x; };
```

to

```
struct Point { int x, y, x; };
struct Data {
  atomic<int> version;
  atomic<Point> point;
};
```

will assure that the `Point` read is actually a `Point` written. Of course, it isn't necessarily the `Point` that corresponds to the given `version`: `point` may already have been overwritten by a *later* version in thread 1 by the time thread 2 gets around to reading it. This could result in the same point being processed twice by thread 2, once with a stale version and again on a later iteration with the proper version. If you need to ensure that each version is processed at most once, you have to verify that `version` is the same *after* reading `point` as it was *before* reading `point`.

Putting it all together, we get this program ([**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1cd76b20ad2bc6bb)):

```
struct Point
{
  int x, y, z;
};

struct Data
{
  std::atomic<int> version;
  std::atomic<Point> point;
};

std::unordered_map<std::string, Data> hashtable;
std::mutex mtx;

Data& lookup(const std::string& key) {
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard{mtx};
  return hashtable[key];
}

void thread1() {
  std::string key;
  Point point;
  std::tie(key, point) = // get new key/point pair
  auto& ref = lookup(key);
  ref.point.store(point, std::memory_order_relaxed);
  ref.version.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_release);
}

void thread2() {
  auto& ref = lookup("string1");
  int local_version = 0;
  for (;;) {
    auto const version = ref.version.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
    if (local_version != version) {
      auto point = ref.point.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
      if (version == ref.version.load(std::memory_order_acquire)) {
        local_version = version;
        // ...process point...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Just to be sure, you are using std::memory_order_relaxed for the load of ref.point , seeing the rest , shouldnt it be order_acquire ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try
https://github.com/Taymindis/atomic_hashtable

The hashing table for read, write, and delete without locking while multithreading doing the thing on buffer, Simple and Stable

API Documents given in Readme.md